# Add rows to grid in extjs dynamically

Tags: json, extjs, grid

I have a grid with one column 'name' which is empty in the start. I also have a JSONObject within which there is an array of fields. I now need to add each field name as a row in the grid dynamically (since the JSONObject I am receiving via REST services). Please advice as to how do I do that.

I wish to know how to add to an empty store dynamically which finally is reflected even after the page is loaded.

e.g.:

```
datajson: {
    ...
    events: {
        'First row' : {
            ...
         }, {
        'Second row' : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So now the grid must contain 'First row' and 'Second row' as the two entries.

Comment: Take a look this [Ext JS example](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/writer/writer-jsonp.html), specifically what happens when the user clicks the "Add" button on the grid.  You should be able to do something very similar.  You'll also need to decode your JSON with [Ext.JSON.decode](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.JSON-method-decode).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example. Its really insightful. In fact it helps me in other areas as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bind a store to your grid

```
{
   xtype: 'grid',
   store: myStore
}
```

then update your store with data

```
myStore.loadData(jsonData)
```

after you can refresh the grid with:

```
myStore.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: You can set a REST proxy to your store too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with another approach :  
Ext.getCmp('name_of_grid').getStore().add({'name' : 'firstrow'});   
I did this inside a for loop.

Comment: My suggestion is not do to so. just not to get a bad habits :)